# Alternating background images of a div automatically?

Tags: javascript, image, background, carousel, intervals

This is what I currently have, and the three background images for div#hero change upon refresh. Is there any easy way to adjust this so that they fade to an alternate image after x number of seconds, instead of upon refresh?

```
<script type="text/javascript">var imgCount = 3;
    var dir = 'images/';
    var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
    var images = new Array
            images[1] = "1.jpg",
            images[2] = "2.jpg",
            images[3] = "3.jpg",
    document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a function and use that inside setInterval method:

```
var interval_time = 5000;//in milliseconds
setInterval(your_function,interval_time);
function your_function(){
var imgCount = 3;
    var dir = 'images/';
    var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
    var images = new Array
            images[1] = "1.jpg",
            images[2] = "2.jpg",
            images[3] = "3.jpg",
    document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
}
```

Now, after each `interval_time` `your_function` would run.

Comment: Thank you! Works. How would I add a smooth transition (fade) between images?